# Get some data from a htm page and save in mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, html-table

I am not a programmer :(

I would like a page where I insert the address from another x.htm page and click "get"

Then I want to save the data in a mysql database, so I can get the data out for each driver.

```html
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <center><b><p>Statistik: 07-02-2022 21:55:35 -  </p></b></center><br />
    <tr bgColor="#999999">
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="30">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Pos </font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="158">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">driver </font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="100">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Car </font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#e5665e" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"> 1-Red</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"> 2-White</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#78ccea" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"> 3-Blue</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffff28" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"> 4-Yellow</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>Best time</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#999999" width="80">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Total laps</font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgColor="#999999">
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="30">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">1</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="158">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">James Hunt</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Alfa Romeo GTA</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>7.952</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>7.963</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>7.975</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>8.088</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>7.952</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana"><b>88.25</b></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgColor="#999999">
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="30">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">2</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="158">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Jackie Stewart</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">Mini Cooper</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">8.176</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">8.194</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">7.989</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">8.197</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">7.989</font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80">
        <div align="center">
          <font face="Verdana">86.68</font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: It is called web scraping - you do not do that with a web page alone. you can write a node.js program using wget or nodefetch or php using curl

Answer (score 0):

Well, man, this is super easy: you can use [QuerySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

See this example based on you code:

```js
const rows = [];
document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr').forEach((tr, rowIndex) => {
    const row = []; 
    tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((item, cellIndex) => {
      console.log(`row ${rowIndex}, cell ${cellIndex}:`, item.textContent.trim());
      row.push(item.textContent.trim());
    });
    rows.push(row);
});
console.log("rows", rows); // you can use this data to save on you database
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <center>
         <b>
            <p>Statistik: 07-02-2022 21:55:35 -  </p>
         </b>
      </center>
      <br />
      <tr bgColor="#999999">
         <td bgcolor="#999999" width="30">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Pos </font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#999999" width="158">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">driver </font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#999999" width="100">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Car </font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#e5665e" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"> 1-Red</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"> 2-White</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#78ccea" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"> 3-Blue</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffff28" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"> 4-Yellow</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#999999" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>Best time</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#999999" width="80">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Total laps</font></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgColor="#999999">
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="30">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">1</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="158">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">James Hunt</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Alfa Romeo GTA</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>7.952</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>7.963</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>7.975</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#87fe58" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>8.088</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>7.952</b></font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana"><b>88.25</b></font></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgColor="#999999">
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="30">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">2</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="158">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Jackie Stewart</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">Mini Cooper</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">8.176</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">8.194</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">7.989</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#b6fea6" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">8.197</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">7.989</font></div>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80">
            <div align="center"> <font face="Verdana">86.68</font></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> **PS:** if you using NodeJS(serverside) maybe you can get the HTML code
> first to then use a dom reader like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to parse HTML and use
> the similar previous solution.

> **PS 2:** you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to handle http/s requests

```
const html = (await axios.get("https://example.com/page.html")).data;
const dom = new JSDOM(html);
const trs = dom.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
```

Comment: Thx it sounds easy but I am totally blank, I need a site where I can put in the name/adress of the result site, press a ok Bottom, check the data as provided as you add, and then press a bottom to save on the database.
Infact I need to manually add a extra data to each result site, a trackname

Comment: The idea is to help you find a solution, not give you a complete source code or something like that...
If you want to finish your project, first, you will need to read more about concepts like Forms, Databases, REST Services, Backend, and Frontend.